# Programmatically scrolling datagridview by increments until it hits bottom, then scroll back to top

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to scroll my Datagridview programmatically by increments of 2. When it reaches the bottom, I'd like to reset the scroll back to the top.

Here is my current code:

```
private int scrollPosition = 0;

            if(scrollPosition == 0)
            {
                // This means the scroll is at the top
                scrollPosition+=2;

            }
            else if(scrollPosition > 0 && scrollPosition < dataGridView1.RowCount-1 -2)
            {
                // This means the scroll is somewhere in the middle
                scrollPosition+=2;
            }
            else
            {
                // This means the scroll is at the bottom
                scrollPosition = 0;

            }
            dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = scrollPosition;
```

That code is inside a method that gets called every 10 seconds.

I have tried debugging the code. Based on what I saw, the code never triggers the else statement. Hence, it does not reset the scroll back to the top. What logic did I do wrong?

Update: My mistake, it triggers the else statement at some point. But it doesn't trigger the else statement the moment the scroll is at the bottom already. Since I have 20 entries in my Datagridview, it takes a while for the scroll position to get near that value.

The Datagridview scroll is already at the bottom before my scrollPosition reaches a value that would trigger the else statement.

Is there a more accurate variable I can compare my scrollPosition to? So that when my Datagridview scroll is at the bottom already, it triggers the else statement as it should at the right time.

Comment: I wrote it for protection. If I tried to compare it directly to dataGridView1.RowCount, there's a chance that the application would crash because the scroll is greater than the RowCount. dataGridView1.RowCount-1 is considered the equivalent of the bottom. And since I'm incrementing by 2, I did dataGridView1.RowCount-1-2. It's quite confusing to me, please suggest a better logic

Comment: You may want to try this: If the scrollposition doesn't change anymore when scrolling down, then you have reached the bottom. The absolute scrollposition values are wanky to say the least, imo..

Comment: TaW, I've found out that even though the Datagridview scroll is at the bottom already, the scrollposition still increments by 2 (it still triggers the second if statement). I have updated my original post. Added more details regarding my debug.

Comment: Is the bottom defined as where only the last one or two rows are visible? Or is the objective to stop as soon as the last row is visible? I would guess the former from your code.

Comment: @Mark- my plan is: when the scroll reaches the bottom already, and my method with the above code gets called, I'd like to reset the scroll back to the top. So pretty much the scroll needs to be at the bottom (i.e. the last row is already visible to the user) before it resets the scroll back to the top.

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculation doesn't take the number of displayed Rows into account.

Here is how you can calculate them, provided the Rows all have the same Height:

```
rVisible = dataGridView1.Height / dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height - 1;
```

Or as Mark suggested:

```
rVisible = dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount(false);
```

Now you can simplify your scrolling code to this:

```
if (dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + rVisible < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex += 2; 
else dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
```

No need for the `scrollPosition` variable.

In your original solution you could also check to see if `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` stops growing, which it does once the last row is visible, but this is simpler. If the rows have varying heights either `DisplayedRowCount` or that latter way should be used so you won't have to sum up the varying heights..

Comment: +1 for the best way I know to do this. Thinking back to an old file browser project though, I remember using a built-in method to get the displayed row count (`dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount(false);` I think it was).

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Thanks for the answer. I tried the solution you and Mark suggested. There is one issue though, the first time it runs my method containing the snippet of code above, it scrolls down fine. But when the method is called again, it doesn't scroll down (and it still haven't reached the bottom yet). What is more confusing is that I tried debugging it and it triggers the if statement as it should. Even though it triggers the code in the 'if' statement and increments FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex by 2, the DGV doesn't scroll down like it should.  Any ideas why?

Comment: It seems that there is an issue with the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex. It doesn't even get incremented even when the code in the 'if' statement gets triggered. I logged it, and the value is always 0.

Comment: Hm, I can't confirm this. I hava a DGV with 33 rows which can display 12 rows. I start a timer with 500ms intervall using the above code and display FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex on the start button's text. It keeps rolling down and jumping back up forever without a problem.. maybe there is more code involved in your programm..?

Comment: Update: I was able to resolve the issue and it's working now. Since the FirstDisplayedScrollingIndex is always 0 (even if incremented), I had to create some temp variable and increment that var instead. Then I set the FirstDisplayedScrollingIndex  value to the temp variable. Pretty much still the same code logic in your answer but I used a temp variable. It's strange that it's behaving this way. My method is pretty much plain. It doesn't contain any other code logic that would affect the scrolling. Anyway, thanks for the help!